# Any legitimate SVN client for Android?

Tags: android, mobile, vpn, subversion

I have an Google Pixel 2 which is obviously running Android.  I have a Cisco App called AnyConnect that lets me through my companies VPN on my phone's. For example I have SSH apps where I can navigate servers behind my firewall when I'm tunneling through the VPN. I'm wondering if there is an Android GUI app that lets me explore my repo? I have not found one that actually works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be worth taking a look at Open Android SVN ([OASVN](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.valleytg.oasvnlite.android&hl=en_GB)) which is available in free, (open source LGPL), and professional versions.

Some features:

- Support for **both** https & svn+ssh protocols (with private keys for the latter).
- Remote Repository browse allows the ability to export any single file to your local file system
- Remote Revision list with complete details of files added/deleted/modified, author, commit comments, date, etc.
- Local Repository browsing allows you to export from your local copy, open files via intent by mime type (should present your with the correct application choices for the job, it is up to the application to respect opening the file by URI) and also shows svn status of files in conflict, or locally updated.

Comment: bullet point missing: not updated since 2012, unless I missed something. But yeah, that's the only one available for Android, to my knowledge.